# How can i get rid of “apache2 : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed” in ubuntu 14.04 desktop?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04, apt, perl, mod-perl

This is the error message i have at console when running

```
$sudo apt-get install apache2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    apache2 : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4) but 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output of update

```
    $sudo apt-get update
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN
Reading package lists... Done
```

I have done recently

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Later i gone to

```
sudo -i software-properties-gtk
```

and checked the canonical checkbox then,

sudo apt-get update this command i executed.

can any one help me to install apache in my ubuntu!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you mix different repos in apt. Sometimes dependencies from different repost don't match and you end up that way.
When you add ppa repos it's a good idea to make sure you are adding the proper repo, compatible with your ubuntu version. Mixing repos for different ubuntu versions or even different distros like debian/mint might work but there is always a chance something will break.

Check this answer from ask ubuntu
https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa